# Make a logger which logs moderator commands, kind of like 'modlogs'

Tags: python, discord.py

How do I make a logger for discord.py bot, which logs all the moderator commands run by the user
Also the files should be auto-generated

Eg.
The bot is in **Server A** and *user1* warns *user2*.

In the logs file named **ServerA.txt**, it saves it as...

> USER1 WARNED USER2 IN {time}.

That's what I need

And when anyone adds the bot to **Server B**, it makes a file named **ServerB.txt**, and logs as coded.

Thank you.

Comment: Which part are you struggling with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry posted that first response before it was ready, reposting now.

Okay, well while I won't provide you with too much specific code, but I can help give you some general architecture and pseudo-code that should help you on your journey here.

Based on exactly what you want done, this is how I'd recommend doing it.

First off, you'll want to `import datetime` if you weren't already, as this is the easiest way to get a log.

Next, you'll want to create a timestamp function which will be called by your logging function to get the exact timestamp format you want.  Something like this will work:

```
def getDate(): #getFormattedDate
    return datetime.datetime.today().strftime("[%y-%m-%d-%H%M%S]-")
```

The above will give a string that (for today and now) might look like this: [2019-12-13-10:42:00]-

Create a function for logging, something like `def serverlog(server, command, ..):`

You'll then want to call this function anytime a loggable command is called on your bot.
 - server will be the `guild.name` on the message
 - command will be whatever moderator command was used
 - .. is just any additional parameters you might see fit, such as `message.author` perhaps, or whoever is being warned.  I'll leave that up to you..

As for the function itself, you'll want to call `getDate()` into whatever string output you're using.  The function will need to open the text file at whatever location you point it to, and if it doesn't exist, then it should create it.

```
def serverlog(server,command,..):
    try:
        check = open(str(server)+"-log.txt","r+")
    except IOError:
        log = open(str(server)+"-log.txt","a+")
        print(str(server)+"-log.txt succesfully created")
        log.close()
    log = open(str(server)+"-log.txt","a", encoding='utf-8')
    log.write(getDate()+.....)
```

`log.write` will be your custom log message that goes into the log file for that particular server, so you can customize it as needed for your purposes.

From there, you'll find your various commands, such as `!warn` and add a line like `serverlog(guild.name, "warn")` to call the logging command.

Below is some old code for a bot I made a while ago on an older version of discord.py, it has a similar-ish logging method and it might be helpful for you: https://github.com/JohnWhy/Jbot-for-Discord/blob/master/Jbot.py

Good luck and have fun!

Comment: Thanks! This is what I exactly needed!